# Сортировка html элементов посредством jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Имеется некий список изображений, который который разделяется на некоторое количество, и в последствии выводится в виде "карусели".

```
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
```

И есть возможность удаления этих фото. Тобишь, жмём по нужной фотке, жмём кнопку удалить, и она удаляется. Но дело в том, что если удалить где - то в середине списка, то будет между этими фотками пробел. Надо его убрать. то есть, сделать так сказать, сортировку, чтобы получилось не:

```
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
```

а что - то типа:

```
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg" />
</div>
```

У кого какие идеи есть? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно стоит попробовать вместо непосредственного удаления фотографии просто заменять ее на одну из фотографий из последнего блока. Но это сработает если фотографии не сортируются по какому-то определенному порядку, а просто формируются в группы изначально.

Comment: Изначально так и сделал. :)  
Сейчас немного переделал код, чтобы не было разделения картинок по 5штук., а выводились все картинки подряд, а JS, уже разделял на нужное количество. )

Answer (score 0):

если выдрать массивом все **src** набора **$('img')** и потом циклом присвоить их (исключив из массива пустые значения)?